# Can a TCP client that send / receives byte[] be created using WCF?

Tags: wcf, tcpclient

I have a TCPclient app which connects to an IP address (ie 127.0.0.1:4005) and sends/receives byte arrays in ASCII format.

Any idea if this is possible to implement also with WCF and if yes, an example of such client will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. You can receive your array in the Stream

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PutData(Stream dataStream);
}
```

and

```
public class Service : IService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "data")]
    public void PutData(Stream dataStream)
}
```

Another way is define your own type as parameter, and implement `IDispatchMessageFormatter` interface, where implement custom request deserialization.